# ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49), when accessing config schema in bitnami openldap docker container

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have deployed the following containet (docker-compose.yaml):

LDAP_CONFIG_ADMIN_ENABLED=true sets by default a config admin user admin/configpassword as stated in the documentation: [link to documentation of bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/openldap/README.md)

```
version: '2'
#https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/openldap/#!
services:
  openldap:
    image: bitnami/openldap:2
    ports:
      - '1389:1389'
      - '1636:1636'
    environment:
      - LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME=AdminCPS
      - LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=passwordCPS
      - LDAP_USERS=user01,user02
      - LDAP_PASSWORDS=password1,password2
      - LDAP_ROOT=dc=ldap_admin
      - LDAP_USER_DC=CPS
      - LDAP_CONFIG_ADMIN_ENABLED=true
    volumes:
      - './openldap_data:/bitnami/openldap'
```

When I try to add this ldif schema (/schema/custom.ldif):

```
version: 1
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.2
        NAME 'gender'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.3
        NAME 'country'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.4
        NAME 'nickName'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.5
        NAME 'timeZone'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.6
        NAME 'dateOfBirth'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.7
        NAME 'role'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.8
        NAME 'im'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.9
        NAME 'url'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.10
        NAME 'otherPhone'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.11
        NAME 'privatePersonalIdentifier'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.12
        NAME 'profileconfiguration'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.13
        NAME 'preferredLanguage'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
-
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37505.1.1
    NAME 'inetCpsPerson'
    DESC 'inetCpsPerson'
    SUP inetOrgPerson
    STRUCTURAL
    MAY  ( gender $ country $ nickName $ timeZone $ dateOfBirth $ role $ im $ url $ otherPhone $ privatePersonalIdentifier $ profileconfiguration $ preferredLanguage)
 )
-
```

I launch this inside the container:

```
ldapmodify -h localhost -p 1389 -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -w configpassword -f /schema/custom.ldif
```

But I get this:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Credentials are correct, perhaps dn is not correct?

Btw, if i try also to access config witn "Apache Directory Studio" for example I cannot manage to enter in the 'cn=config' domain with admin/configpassword credentials.... same error: Invalid credentials (49)

Comment: Credentials are *not* correct. The error message said so. 'Credentials' consist of both the DN and the password.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Those credentials no longer are used in version 2. I have changed to version 2.6 of image and works perfectly.